# Android Emulator hangs with black screen on startup

Tags: android, android-emulator

This has been posted here in StackOverflow several times, but unfortunately I cannot get any solution from previous posts to work. When starting the android emulator, it hangs and shows a black screen. I have tried launching it from both Visual Studio and from AVD Manager. Things I have tried:

- Waiting for over 10 minutes
- Using both Hyper V and HAXM
- Changing the Emulated Performance to both Hardware and Software
- Changing the config.ini for the device to enable/disable GPU
- Changing the config.ini for the device to different GPU modes (i.e., host)
- Changing the amount of RAM
- Reinstalling ADV and Android SDKs
- Quit Forwarding in ADB
- Deleted and recreated the device (and several others)
- "Wiped Data" in ADV. Factory reset in Visual Studio
- Ran from Cold Boot
- Tried running from both x86 and x86_x64 devices (Google API and Google Play)
- Disabling antivirus and firewalls

Other notes. This is a brand new PC with Windows 10, 16 gb ram, i7 processor, NVIDIA 2060 graphics.
I am out of ideas. Please help.